# Cascade insert of new and existing entities

Tags: java, spring, entity-framework, hibernate, jpa

I have a 'tag' mechanism (kind of like Gmail's labels) with which I want to tag another entity, for the sake of the question - employees.

The Tag entity is simple and contains only name and looks as follows:

```
@Entity
public class Tag implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "tag_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "name", unique = true)
  private String name;

  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "tags")
  private Set<Employee> employees = new HashSet<>(0);
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(final String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public Set<Employee> getEmployees() {
    return employees;
  }
```

}

My Employee entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class Employee implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -6809049173391335091L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "employee_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
  private Long id;

  @Column
  private String name;

  @Column
  private String description;

  @Column
  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
  @JoinTable(name = "employee_tag", joinColumns = {
      @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) },
      inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id",
              nullable = false, updatable = false) })
  private List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<>();

  // Rest of Getters and Setters


  public List<Tag> getTags() {
    return tags;
  }

  public void setTagsFromString(final String tags) {    
    String[] realTagsSplitted = tags.split(",");
    for(String tagString: realTagsSplitted) {
      Tag tag = new Tag();
      tag.setName(tagString);
      this.tags.add(tag);
  }
}
```

What I would like to do is to be able to add from the UI tags to an Employee entity. But the tags are plain strings in the UI. I would like that when the Employee entity is persisted to have the tags persisted as well **BUT** I don't want duplications in the tags table (by duplication I, of course, mean that no two tags should exist with the same name but different ids).

Meaning - if the tag "Tag1" exists in the table and the tag "Tag2" doesn't and in the UI the user adds both "Tag1" and "Tag2" to Employee "Employee1" I would like to:

1. Create a new row in the join-table that binds the id of "Employee1" to the id of "Tag1".
2. Create a new row in the Tag table with "Tag2"
3. Create a new row in the join-table that binds the id of "Employee1" to the id of the newly created "Tag2".

I really prefer to handle it on the code level, preferably with annotations if a solution exists. I'm trying to avoid DB triggers and things that are not obvious from reading the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle this on the service level, not in entities. Something along these steps:

1. Create a method like `findOrCreateTag(tagName)`, which would return existing tag from the database if it exists, or create a new one if it doesn't exist
2. Call this method for each tag you get from UI, and add it to `employee#tags` (also, add the employee to `tag#employees`)
3. Save changes to employee

One small thing, remove `@Column` from `Employee#tags` mapping.